# Should I fight the police or run away?

Tags: dopewars

In [dopewars](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dopewars/), should I fight the law enforcement officers or run away? I fought and got rid of Officer Hardass and Officer Bob by fighting them. I also got rid of Agent Smith a few times, but it seems that he never really dies. If I am always going to encounter the police, why should I fight them? Fighting has the disadvantage of causing the deaths of lots of my "bitches", while running away causes fewer losses. Is there any advantage in fighting the police? Should I always try to run away?

Comment: Haven't played in years, but back in the day I only fought them if they forced it -- i.e. when they attack if I try to run. This helped sometimes, but the RNG can be mean.